# Unable to pass a dynamically generated array of cacheable links to Service Worker

Tags: javascript, node.js, service-worker

How do I pass a programmatically populated array of links to a service worker script for caching?

I am generating the array in **cachelist.js** like this:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
require('dotenv').config();

var cachedItems = ['/'];
function walkSync(currentDirPath, callback) {
    fs.readdirSync(currentDirPath).forEach(function (name) {
        var filePath = path.join(currentDirPath, name);
        var stat = fs.statSync(filePath);
        if (stat.isFile()) {
            callback(filePath, stat);
        } else if (stat.isDirectory()) {
            walkSync(filePath, callback);
        }
    });
}

walkSync('./pages/', function(filePath, stat) {
  cachedItem = filePath.substr(5);
  if(cachedItem.indexOf('_') == -1) {
    cachedItems.push(cachedItem);
  }
});

module.exports = { cachedItems };
```

And then I'm trying to use this cachedItems array in **/offline/serviceWorker.js** as follows:

```
const URLSTOCACHE = require("../cachelist.js");
const CACHE_NAME = "version-0.0.46";

// Call install event
self.addEventListener("install", e => {
  e.waitUntil(
    caches
    .open(CACHE_NAME)
    .then(cache => cache.addAll(URLSTOCACHE))
    .then(() => self.skipWaiting())
  );
});

// Call fetch event
self.addEventListener("fetch", e => {
  e.respondWith(
    fetch(e.request).catch(() => caches.match(e.request))
  )
});
```

However, this fails with an "*Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined.*" Any workaround?

Comment: node.js code such as methods on the `fs` module do not run in the browser (which I presume is where you are trying to run a service-worker).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`require` isn't a built-in browser-side utility. There are various libraries (like RequireJS) and bundlers (which rewrite the require call), but unless you're using one of those, you can't use `require` browser-side.

If your goal is to read that file in the service worker and add the URLs in it to the cache, use `fetch` to load it, and then use thme in `addAll`.

Comment: I don't want to hard-code the list of url's in my addAll call which is why I'm generating the array dynamically. I wonder if there's any alternative workaround to accomplish this without involving require().

Comment: @TheLearner - Fetch them from your server with an ajax call or embed the array into a `<script>` tag in the web page when the page is served from your web server so then they would be available to your client-side browser code later when it runs.

Comment: @TheLearner - Then use `fetch` in your service worker to load the list, and then add the URLs to cache once you have the list. I've updated the answer.